# Enable logging in Scalardb

Tags: scalardb

How do I enable logging in Scalardb? Does it support logback? The ScalarDB logic in my application is throwing NullPointerException. I want to enable traces to understand where the problem might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalar DB uses slfj4 so various logging frameworks such as logback and log4j can be used.
https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/blob/master/build.gradle

You need to build your application with such logging frameworks and configure
them properly.
For more information regarding slf4j, please refer to [slf4j site](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

Comment: Thanks. What is the selector I need to use to enable logging in logback.xml? Would it be `com.scalar-labs`.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work - `<logger name="com.scalar" level="DEBUG" additivity="true"> <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> </logger>`